# Image resizing not working with Intervention image Package

Tags: laravel, intervention

The photo is saved, but without resizing, the original photo is actually saved

```
protected function uploadImage($images = '') {
    $path = 'upload/images';
    if (request()->hasFile('image') && $files = request()->file('image'))
        $images = Image::make($files->store($path, 'public_files'))->resize(320, 240);
    return $images;
}
```

```
public function store(CreateGalleryRequest $request, Job $job) {
    $image = $this->uploadImage();
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $data['image'] = $image . $image->dirname . '/' . $image->basename;
    } else
        $data['image'] = null;
    $job->gallery()->create($data);
    return redirect(route('jobs.gallery.index' , ['job' => $job->id]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `save()` function to save image

```php
...
$images = Image::make($files->store($path, 'public_files'))->resize(320, 240)->save('image path');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

wrote:

```
$images = Image::make($files->store($path, 'public_files'))->resize(320, 240)->save($files->store($path, 'public_files'));
```

error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
```

actually there is an error in the following code:

```
$job->gallery()->create($data);
```